# Why does @RelatedToVia have optional type and elementClass parameters?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

`@RelatedToVia` in Spring-Data-Neo4j annotates a field on a `NodeEntity` object as a reference to a `@RelationshipEntity` object connecting that node to another node. `@RelatedTo`, in contrast, marks the field as a reference to the connected node itself, and has an optional `type` parameter that can be used to specify the type of relationship between the two nodes.

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="SOME_LINK")
class SomeLink { 
    @StartNode 
    FooNode foo;

    @EndNode 
    BarNode bar;
}

@NodeEntity
class FooNode {
    @RelatedTo(type="SOME_LINK")
    BarNode bar;

    @RelatedToVia(type="SOME_LINK") //what's the point in this annotation? 
    SomeLink link; 
}
```

`@RelatedToVia` has the same optional `type` parameter, and I'm curious about why that is: The type of relationship is specified in the field type (a field annotated with `@RelatedToVia` must be typed to a `@RelationshipEntity`-annotated class, which must specify a type to compile), so what would be the point of specifying it in the annotation parameter?

Even more confusingly, `@RelatedToVia` also has an optional `elementClass` parameter that, according to the docs, "returns the target relationship entity class" - which is *exactly* what's specified in the field type.

```
@RelatedToVia(elementClass=SomeLink.class)  //what's the point? 
SomeLink link; 

@RelatedToVia(elementClass=SomeOtherLink.class)  // ???? 
SomeLink link;
```

I'm curious because I have a hunch that this was intended to enable some useful polymorphic behavior with `RelationshipEntity` classes and `RelatedToVia` fields, and I'd love to see an example of how such behavior might be implemented. As a bonus, what *different* sorts of behaviors can be achieved using the two different annotations?

Also, it seems curious that both these parameters exist for (possibly redundantly) specifying the type of the relationship, while no parameter exists for specifying the class of the *node* on the other end of the relationship - which can be but isn't necessarily declared in the `RelationshipEntity` class, and which would have been useful to me on a couple of occasions. Why might that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
@RelatedToVia(type="SOME_LINK")
```

has precedence over

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="SOME_LINK")
```

and

```
@RelatedToVia(elementClass=SomeOtherLink.class)  // this is indeed redundant
SomeLink link;

// this is NOT redundant, you lose the type information in runtime in Java
// you only know that link is a set, don't know of which type
@RelatedToVia(elementClass=SomeOtherLink.class)      
Set<SomeLink> link;
```

Having multiple ways to set the relationship gives you flexibility. You can reuse the same relationship class for multiple different relationship types that have same properties.

See more in reference docs

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/programming-model.html#reference_programming_model_relationships_relationshiptypeprecedence

Comment: What do you mean `@RelatedToVia` has precedence over `@RelationshipEntity`? There is never a situation where the two can be present in the same class?

Comment: Relation ship type defined in @ RelatedToVia will be taken first, if it is not defined then type defined in @RelationshipEntity. You can use both, but only @ RelatedToVia will be used. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/15cc8418ed4d429a952b86f788717add8a93f76c/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/mapping/RelationshipInfo.java#L101